# How to overcome client error in aws sagemaker when I try to create a S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-s3

I am getting ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Access Denied when I try to create aws s3 bucket from the notebook instance of aws sagemaker.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQVUw.png) Please anyone reply to this issue to solve.

Comment: Please post code as text (correctly formatted) not as an image. Have you read https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-s3-accessdenied-training/?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.